# i could not installl a openpose library from c++ for pose detection

Tags: c++, machine-learning, openpose, pose-detection

I have installed the OpenPose library for my pose detection project using C++. However, I am encountering difficulties with the installation process, particularly when trying to download models as per the instructions provided on https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpose.mirror/.

These are the instructions they have provided:

```
1. Double click on `models/getBaseModels.bat` to download the required body, face, and hand models.
    - Optional: Double click on `models/getCOCO_and_MPII_optional.bat` to download the COCO and MPII models (slower and less accurate, only download them if you really have a reason to do so).
2. Check all the info in:
    - https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/tree/v1.7.0
    - https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/v1.7.0/doc/
3. Specially, the C++ quick start guide:
    - https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/v1.7.0/doc/quick_start.md
4. For Python, check both the C++ quick start guide (same flags) and the Python testing doc:
    - https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/v1.7.0/doc/quick_start.md
    - https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/v1.7.0/doc/modules/python_module.md#testing, but replace "cd build/examples/tutorial_api_python" by "cd python/".
        - NOTE: The rest of the python_module.md instructions are for the GitHub source code library, you can ignore them here.
    - Python code example:

cd {OpenPose_root_path}
cd python/
python openpose_python.py
```

However, when I attempt to run the models/getBaseModels.bat script from the downloaded folder, it does not download or install anything. Instead, it continuously attempts to download without any success. Here's a snippet of the output I'm seeing in the command prompt:

```
------------------------- BODY, FOOT, FACE, AND HAND MODELS -------------------------
----- Downloading body pose (COCO and MPI), face and hand models -----

------------------------- POSE (BODY+FOOT) MODELS -------------------------
Body (BODY_25)
--2023-08-23 12:50:47--  http://posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu/OpenPose/models/pose/body_25/pose_iter_584000.caffemodel
Resolving posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu (posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu)... 64:ff9b::8002:dc39, 128.2.220.57
Connecting to posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu (posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu)|64:ff9b::8002:dc39|:80... failed: Unknown error.
Connecting to posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu (posefs1.perception.cs.cmu.edu)|128.2.220.57|:80...
```

Due to this issue, I am unable to proceed further with my project. Can you please provide a solution or suggest an alternative approach for pose detection and obtaining key coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Their service is down, but you can download them from the Google drive.
You can refer to this GitHub issue
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/2233#issuecomment-1690823950